# C++ std move document error?

Tags: c++, c++11, move

Here is the [document](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) I am referring to. Both form has r-value reference as input (`T&& t`).

But we can put l-value as parameter of `move`, in my below example, a is a l-value, which is identifiable and memory-addressable.

Any thought is document is wrong?

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    string a = "hello";
    string b(std::move(a));
    std::cout << "a is: " << a << endl;
    std::cout << "b is: " << b << endl;
}
```

output,

```
a is: 
b is: hello
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`T&& t` is not r-value reference. It is the forward reference, previously known as  universal reference, the special case when used with template or auto parameters. Read this good explanation here https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers

Comment: They're called [forwarding references.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references)

Comment: Thanks SM. But still a bit lost, I think in C++ 11, there is new r-value reference and we are normally use && to represent it, for example, push_back method is overloaded to have & (l-value reference) and && (r-value reference), refer to => http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/

Comment: Do you mean && could be used for both l-value reference and r-value reference?

Comment: @LinMa `&&` has a different meaning in a template argument. Look at the linked article for an explanation. The "universal reference" is now called a "forwarding reference".

Comment: @LinMa I think two overloads for `std::vector::push_back` exist due to backward compatibility. If it would be a new method introduced in C++11, then it would be most probably one with a forward reference.

Comment: Thanks SM, nice link, mark your reply as answer. Good to learn from you && has two meanings. :)